# Azure Data Factory copy pipeline: get a file with date of yesterday that arrived today

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am getting a txt file (on todays date) with the date of yesterday in it and I want dynamically get this filename in my data factory pipeline.

The file is placed automatically on a file system and I want to copy this file to the blob store In my example below I am simulating this by copying from blob to blob.

**For example:**
filename_2018-02-11.txt arrived today (2018-03-12) with the date of yesterday(2018-02-11). How can I pick this file up on today's date? 
Yesterday's slice did run but there was not a file yet.

Here is my example:

```
 {"$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Pipeline.json",
"name": "CopyPipeline-fromBlobToBlob",
"properties": {
"activities": [
  {
    "type": "Copy",
    "typeProperties": {
      "source": {
        "type": "BlobSource",
        "recursive": true
      },
      "sink": {
        "type": "BlobSink",
        "copyBehavior": "",
        "writeBatchSize": 0,
        "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
      },
      "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true
    },
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "InputDataset-1"
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "OutputDataset-1"
      }
    ],
    "policy": {
      "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
      "concurrency": 1,
      "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
      "style": "StartOfInterval",
      "retry": 3,
      "longRetry": 0,
      "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
    },
    "scheduler": {
      "frequency": "Day",
      "interval": 1,
      "offset": "05:00:00"
    },
    "name": "activity_00"
  }
],
"start": "2018-03-07T00:00:00Z",
"end": "2020-03-08T00:00:00Z",
"isPaused": false,
"pipelineMode": "Scheduled"

}
}
```

Comment: Rerunning the slice is not an option?

Comment: @SimonZeinstra Is there an option to rerun the slice automatically? or just manually possible? If a automated solution is possible that will work for me.

Comment: Not from the Data Factory itself, it would require some coding. It's possible to re-run slices using PowerShell or anything that can talk to the Data Factory API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EndOfInterval` instead of `StartOfInterval` in the policy. That will use the end of the day instead of the start of the day to do the execution. You may also want to set the appropriate offset if the file is not available at midnight.

Comment: Thanks!! EndOfInterval helped me. I keep using offset at5:00 so my pipelines will run at 5:00 the next day. I am also using longretry 5 so that I keey trying checking if the file has arrived. The callenge here is that I get error messages till the file is there...

Answer (score 2):

In ADF v2 you can use inbuilt variables (`@pipeline().TriggerTime`):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables

And in a source data set (InputDataset-1) put file path/file name as something like this:

`@concat('YOUR BASE PATH IN BLOB/', 'filename_', 
    addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -1, 'yyyy'), '-', 
    addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -1, 'MM'), '-', 
    addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -1, 'dd'), '.txt'))`

You can also use `@trigger().scheduledTime`
To have always the same date when e.g. pipeline will fail.
But remember that it is only available in trigger scope. 
In my tests it was only evaluated for Schedule trigger.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is regarding to DF v2? I am currently using data factory v1.

Comment: Yes that's for DF v2.